# How can I make ExCel generate a simple plot of value vs day if the days span more than one year?

Tags: excel

ExCel 365
ExCel novice, so please bear with me....

If I have a spreadsheet with 2 columns, a date and a value.  I want to plot the value (Y-axis) as it changes per day (X-axis). So I go ahead and select some day/values from my spreadsheet which just happen so span from late November to early December, a total of 6 values (keeping it simple).

Next I insert a pivot table and the "Pivot Table Fields" pane pops up.  At the top I see the first date, and the first value.  So I drag the date down to the "Rows" sub-pane.  A "Months" line pops up at the top of the Pivot Table Pane and it's selected.  My 6 data points have been reduced to 2, one for November, one for December.  I don't want that so I deselect the "Month" and Viola! I have my 6 dates back.  I proceed to finish the plot successfully.  That's when the dates span across more than one month.

Now, Same thing only they span over 2 years.  Still a puny 6 dates, the last 3 days of December 2016 and the first 3 of January 2017.  Just like before I drag the date down to the "Rows" sub-pane only this time I no longer get the "Months" but get instead "Years" and "Quarters".  Not terribly surprising, I know what to do, I deselect Years and Quarters but there is no "Months" to delelect.  And after deselecting Years and Quarters, my 6 dates have been reduced to 2 months, December and January.  There is no "Months" to deselect so I can't re-expand to get my 6 dates.  And of course I can't generate the plot of the 6 days vs value because it lost it's sense of the days (apparently)

Is there a way I can get the day resolution back for plotting ?

Answer (score 0):

With your data selected, try inserting the pivot table with these steps:
Select table or range
New or existing worksheet (whichever you prefer)
Then check the box "Add this data to the Data Model".  This is the key to what you're looking for, I believe.
Click ok and the data should be laid out horizontally with the dates specified.

As much as I advocate pivot tables, they can sometimes be too smart for their own good.  Is there a reason not to use a chart here?  With the chart, you can right click the date axis, select "Format axis..." and then under Axis type, select "Text axis". That will prevent Excel from being too helpful and inserting all the dates in between the dates in your data.